# Date formating issue having + sign

Tags: java, datetime

I have date `2016-03-30T23:59:59.000000+0000`. May I know what format it is in.
because if I use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`, it is throwing an exception

Comment: The `+0000` is the timezone offset.

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) gives you the answer:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really have **microseconds different from zero** then I strongly advise not to use `SimpleDateFormat` but Java-8-Time-API or another time library which can handle microseconds. And this is not the only case where the old API proves to be very limited.

Negative example for `SimpleDateFormat` (broken, milliseconds disappear!!!):

```
String input = "2016-03-30T23:59:59.123456+0530";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(input))); // 2016-03-30T18:32:02.000456+0000
```

Java-8-example (works):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
System.out.println(odt); // 2016-03-30T23:59:59.123456+05:30
```

If you never have microseconds but only milliseconds and want to insist on using the old API then you might try following hack:

```
    String input = "2016-03-30T23:59:59.123000+0530";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'xxx'Z");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(input.replace("000", "xxx"))));
```

2016-03-30T18:29:59.123+0000

However, this "solution" breaks for year 2000 (you can find a better one by further string preprocessing), and eventually available microseconds get lost. So using `SimpleDateFormat` is a bad idea here.